# Listen to an event when a class has been added to an html element using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scrollspy

I am using scroll spy from `bootstrap`. An `active` class gets added when scrolling element comes into view.
This is the normal behavior of scroll spy.

I am just trying to get notified when active class gets added to an li element.

```
<li
    key       = {`${idx}`}
    className = "panel "
>
    <a
        href        = {`#${groupId}`}
        data-toggle = "collapse"
        data-parent = {`#${accordionId}`}
        data-target = {`#Menu${idx}`}
        className   = "temp-link"
    >
      Menu
    </a>
    <ul className="nav nav-list panel-collapse collapse " id={`${ulIdx}`}>
          <li> .... </li>
          <li> .... </li>
          <li> .... </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I am just trying to attach event handler to parent `li` which will get called when it gets `active` class. 
At that time I will show `ul` element via adding class `collapse in`.
I am using ReactJs and does not want to use any jquery based solutions.
Any simpler javascript based solutions, ideas or suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You're probably better off using [react-scrollspy](http://makotot.github.io/react-scrollspy/) or [react-waypoint](http://brigade.github.io/react-waypoint/) for this, it seems overly complex to listen for that change.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [`MutationObserver` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

It allows you to observe a specific DOM element for changes and executes a callback if such a change occurs. The remaining functionality should be trivial to implement.

> `MutationObserver` provides developers a way to react to changes in a DOM. It is designed as a replacement for Mutation Events defined in the DOM3 Events specification.